# Extension of a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, finite-groups, quotient-group

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups such that $f:G/Z(G)\rightarrow H/Z(H)$ be an isomorphism. Now let $A$ and $B$ be normal subgroups of $G$ and $H$ respectively. If I define a map by $g:\frac{G}{A}\rightarrow\frac{H}{B}$ by $g(xA)=f(x)B$ then what conditions on $g$ should be imposed so that it becomes an isomorphism, where $f(x)$ is the image of $xZ(G)$ under $f$ without consedring the quotient.

> My attempt The map $g$ should be well defined, for this $A\subseteq Z(G)$, $B\subseteq Z(H)$ and $f(AZ(G))\subseteq BZ(H)$ should be the necessary conditions. If the map is well defined then there is no problem in being an homomorphism. Now please give me some idea to find minimal condition on $f$ and $g$ so that $g$ become bijective.

Comment: You need to be a little more careful, saying "$f(A) \subset B$" does not make sense here since $f$ is not a map into $H$, but into $H/Z(H)$.

Comment: Even writing $f(x)$ is problematic.

Comment: @D_S thanks for correcting me. I have edited the question, please have a look on this.

Comment: I mean, another obvious condition, but nowhere near sufficient, is that $Z(G)/A$ is isomorphic to $Z(H)/B$. You then need to learn about cohomology. A sufficient, but not necessary condition would then be that the elements of the cohomology groups are equal.